# Handle end of custom transition when not animated?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, custom-transition

I'm using a custom transition in my app.

I have an `animateTransition` method, which gives me a `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`, and allows me to set the `containerView.backgroundColor` to `UIColor.blackColor()` in the completion of the `UIView.animate..` block.

The problem comes if I call `presentViewController:` with animated set to  `false`. No animation means the `animateTransition` method is never called, and so my background isn't turned to black as intended.

I was wondering how else I'd be able to set the container view's background color to black, without animating the custom transition in.

By the way, not animating it in doesn't mean that I wouldn't be animating it out. And removing it on the animate in doesn't help matters, as it still doesn't give me an opportunity to make the containerView black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it inside the View Controllers viewDidLoad -method, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```